# How to properly declare Array type when initializing struct in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to initialize a struct so I can parse from a JSON file in Swift. I have the following written:

```
struct StopDescription: Decodable {
    let stopId: String
    let translocStopId: String
    let stopName: String
    let stopDesc: String
    let stopLat: String
    let stopLon: String
    let directionId: String
    let times: [String]
}
```

In order to parse from this JSON code:

```
{
    stop_id: "M1",
    transloc_stop_id: "4160714",
    stop_name: "blank",
    stop_desc: "blank",
    stop_lat: "142",
    stop_lon: "-171",
    direction_id: "1",
    times: [
        "7:00 AM",
        "7:30 AM",
        "8:00 AM",
        "8:30 AM",
        "8:45 AM",
        "9:00 AM",
        "9:30 AM",
        "10:00 AM",
        "10:30 AM",
        "11:00 AM",
        "11:30 AM"
    ]
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if my Array declaration for the `times` variable is correct. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's a lot easier if you paste the code as formatted text into your question. Following the links for images isn't helpful.

Comment: I apologize. I have edited the comment accordingly.

Comment: Technically, your JSON is not JSON. You have to double quote the keys as well as the string values. If your JSON parser is bailing, that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Be sure to either add a `CodingKeys` enum or more preferably use the `.convertFromSnakeCase` as the `keyDecodingStrategy` when you parse the JSON.

```
struct StopDescription: Codable {
    let stopId, translocStopId, stopName, stopDesc: String
    let stopLat, stopLon, directionId: String
    let times: [String]
}

let let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

let stopDescription = try? decoder.decode(StopDescription.self, from: jsonData)
```